# How common is Yichud?

Tags: lomdus, yichud-seclusion, tractate-sotah, sotah-secluded-woman

> דתניא רבי יוסי ברבי יהודה אומר משום ר' אליעזר המקנא לאשתו מקנא ע"פ עד אחד או ע"פ עצמו ומשקה לה על פי שנים השיבו חכמים לדברי רבי יוסי ברבי יהודה אין לדבר סוף מ"ט דר' יוסי ברבי יהודה אמר קרא בה בה ולא בסתירה ואימא בה ולא בקינוי קינוי איתקש לטומאה דכתיב וקנא את אשתו והיא נטמאה סתירה נמי איתקש לטומאה דכתיב ונסתרה והיא נטמאה ההוא לכמה שיעור סתירה כדי טומאה הוא דאתא השיבו חכמים לדברי ר' יוסי בר' יהודה אין לדבר סוף מאי ניהו דזמנין דלא קני ואמר קנאי הא למשנתינו יש לדבר סוף זמנין דלא איסתתר ואמר איסתתר אמר רב יצחק בר יוסף א"ר יוחנן אף לדברי רבי יוסי בר' יהודה אין לדבר סוף אף לדברי רבי יוסי בר' יהודה ולא מיבעיא למשנתינו אדרבה למשנתינו איכא עיקר התם ליכא עיקר

Rashi:

> מאי ניהו. אין לדבר סוף דקאמר: ואמר קנאי. כשכועס עליה אומר קנאתי לה מפלוני ומביא עדים שנסתרה עמו סתירה כל שהוא דכיון דלא קינא לה לא נזהרה בו:

[— Sotah 2b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=2b&format=text)

Rashi said that the *big* danger is that the husband will want to divorce his wife, claim that he warned her, and then find witnesses that there was Yichud, which is fairly common?

*Fairly common?*

It's an biblical prohibition to have Yichud with a married a woman. Why would a regular, religious woman have Yichud with a stranger?

Comment: Idolatry is also a biblical prohibition, yet it was still quite common in the time of Tanach.

Comment: I don't think most women would violate *yichud*. My reading of Rashi was that it is a situation where the husband already suspects her of being involved with Ploni. Let's say he decides he wants to divorce her at this point. If he warns her, she may heed his warning. This would mean she wouldn't forfeit her *kesuba*. If he doesn't warn her, she will likely continue her dalliance with Ploni, at which point her husband can catch her (with witnesses) and not have to pay her *kesuba* if he falsely claims that he gave her prior warning.